# Override Specific Style Properties using Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design

I am trying to override the styles of [Material Design for Xaml ToolKit](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) as per my requirements, the following is the xaml in **app.xaml** which i came up with after reading about overriding on the github page of the library, but it seems to be not working and i am not getting why, as i have not much experience working in WPF applications, here is the code i tried:

```
<Color x:Key="DarkBlueColor">#00479D</Color>
<FontFamily x:Key="MicrosoftYaHei">Microsoft YaHei</FontFamily>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBrush" Color="#00479D"/>

<Style x:Key="WindowStyle" 
       x:Name="WindowStyle" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignPaper}" 
       TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBrush}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

For the time being to get familiar i am only trying to change the background of the window, here is the code from **MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XCMG.CarMan2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

When i run the application after adding the above code, it throws an exception saying:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' to type 'System.Windows.Style'.

Answer (score 2):

"MaterialDesignPaper" is a `SolidColorBrush` and you can't base a `Window` style on a `Brush`.

Remove the `BasedOn` attribute and the `x:Name` from your `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBrush}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

> but i want override MaterialDesignBrush BackGround

Define a new `Brush` resource with the same key then:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignPaper" Color="#00479D"/>
```

Comment: but i want override MaterialDesignBrush BackGround

Comment: Define a new Brush resource with the same key then. See my edited answer.

Comment: will it just override the Color property of existing Style with this key which is in another dll?

Comment: It will override the resource which means that all styles that reference this resource using the DynamicResource markup extension should be affected. Make sure that you add your resource *after* you have merged in the other resources.

Comment: But please provide a repo of your issue if you need anu further help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i means was will it just override that specific property only, i want other properties of that Resource to apply that already provided by the dll, but i want to use custom color only

Comment: It will only override the brush named "MaterialDesignPaper". This may be used to set several different properties of several different controls. Why don't you try it out for yourself?

Comment: Did you try this or what happened?